# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php

Queria criar uma dropdown, mas ao fazer aparece o seguinte erro.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in **line 96**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">User:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="user" id="user">

        <option value = "0">No user</option>
        <?php>
            $q = "SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY first ASC";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            while ($user_list= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                $user_data = data_user($dbc, $user_list['id']);
                ?>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $user_data['fullname']; ?></option>

                <?php 
            } \\LINHA 96
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quando você está abrindo a tag PHP vc colocou o carácter `>`, Retire ele e seu erro possivelmente vai sumir.

```
<?php
    $q = "SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY first ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    while ($user_list= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $user_data = data_user($dbc, $user_list['id']);
 ?>
 <option value="0"><?php echo $user_data['fullname']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Não percebo porque está recebendo votos negativos quando na realidade me ajudou no problema.

Comment: Meu amigo, é complicado, não posso explica o outro voto negativo, mas posso explicar **o meu**, pelo mesmo motivo que a pergunta foi fechada como `Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação.`, Mesmo estando certa, acredito que responder esse tipo de pergunta acaba incentivando perguntas do mesmo tipo.... Pode ter sido exagero da minha parte, mas é minha visão...

Comment: Acredito ainda que sua resposta seria mais bem aceita se fosse apenas um comentário, e não uma resposta.

Esse é o tipo de pergunta que o maior problema é a pergunta em sí, e não a resposta, mas acaba indo "no bonde".